# Add the custom widget value to the array on wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a home page banner in our WordPress website. Added a logic to show different images on page refresh.

The code for the images are placed in the help_functions.php, updated the file and it worked as expected.

```
$images = array( "https://images.pexels.com/photos/325185/pexels-photo-325185.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3787839/pexels-photo-3787839.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3769312/pexels-photo-3769312.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940")

            $rand_img = array_rand($images, 1);
            $image =$images[$rand_img];
```

Instead of hardcoding, I register a new custom widget by adding below code in the functions.php

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__('Splash images Widget', 'wpresidence'),
        'id' => 'splashimage-widget-area',
        'description' => esc_html__('The splash image widget area', 'wpresidence'),
        'before_widget' => ' ',
        'after_widget' => ' ',
        'before_title' => ' ',
        'after_title' => ' ',
    ));


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widgets' );
```

and I added the custom html to the widget and added the below code

```
array( "https://images.pexels.com/photos/325185/pexels-photo-325185.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3787839/pexels-photo-3787839.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3769312/pexels-photo-3769312.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940")
```

And tried updating the code in help_functions.php file as below

```
$images = dynamic_sidebar( 'splashimage-widget-area' );

            $rand_img = array_rand($images, 1);
            
            $header_type=20;
            
            $image =$images[$rand_img];
```

Its not working as expected.

Expected result, Add images link in the widget and update the help_functions.php file to show the different images on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

> I register a new custom widget

You are registering an area for the widgets using `register_sidebar()`, not the widget itself.

This widget area allows you to assign widgets (custom HTML, image, recent posts etc) into that area and specify where you want them to appear in your template files.

To register a widget you need to use `register_widget()` function and class, see this tutorial on [how to create your first widget](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/).

However, if you don't want to register new widget you can register shortcode that outputs what you want, then add it via a custom html/text widget.

Registering shortcode is very easy using `add_shortcode()` function, especially if you plan to hardcode an array of images and not pass any attributes.

More on [registering shortcode here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/).